# AnyConnect disconnect then reconnect when starting a new docker container

Tags: docker, cisco

I connect to my company VPN with AnyConnect (using this rather than openconnect to allow single sign on to work).

When I run a docker container that's not using network driver "host", my VPN disconnects then reconnects. My VPN connection is still functional on the host and any containers running with network driver "host" can still access VPN resources.

So everything works. What is like to know is what exactly is causing this behaviour and when I know that, is there anything I can do to prevent it.

`docker create network -d bridge my_network` doesn't cause the disconnect. It's only when I use the network (and `ip link show` shows it's created a virtual Ethernet interface using my bridge as master) that the disconnect and reconnect happens.

---

I have docker and Cisco AnyConnect on an Ubuntu based distribution (though have seen this same behaviour on OpenSuse and Fedora)

### Update

I have realised today that when building a container, it also disconnects and reconnects the Linux Cisco AnyConnect client.

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same error.You try reinstall ubuntu!